# Reputation not added for suggested edits

Tags: discussion, suggested-edits, reputation

I have suggested some edits and 5 of them were approved. But reputation didn't added up. Same for yesterday. Is something wrong?

[image: Missing Reputations]

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Per [How do suggested edits work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/76251/how-do-suggested-edits-work)

> When a suggested edit is approved, the user who suggested it gets +2 reputation. The regular daily reputation cap applies, and **the total cap for reputation gained via suggested edits is 1,000**. Like any other reputation, the +2 is reversed if the edited post is ever deleted.

Given that you've had 550 edit suggestions approved, and 72 edit suggestions rejected (and get 2 rep per edit), you've surpassed the 1,000 rep limit, and so no longer get reputation for suggested edits.

Comment: Huh, TIL. Is there a reason that there's a cap for suggested edits? I would guess that it's because by that time you should have enough rep to directly edit posts, but that's not a guarantee.

Comment: Am I correct in inferring that you can't reach 2,000 rep by suggested edits alone?

Comment: @Keale That is correct