# Loss of reputation and loss of privileges: should they always be connected?

Tags: discussion, reputation, privileges

I recently got the Edit Questions and Answers privilege in Stack Overflow. I had exactly 2,000 rep.

I decided to spend some time in reviewing and I found a post that, in my opinion, required a downvote.
As I applied the downvote I realized that I had lost the just acquired privilege, since my rep was now down to 1,999.

This is a limit scenario (and definitely a not so important one), but I think I would have given a poor service to the community if, for fear of losing the recently acquired privilege, I would have just ignored the post, leaving for someone else the dirty job.

So, here are some questions that come to my mind:

- Does that make sense to lose a privilege only due to a loss of rep without keeping other factors in consideration? (especially when you loose the privilege because you are actually doing something good for the community... maybe in this case a badge should be awarded ;) )
- Are there other scenarios in which it would be fair (with a good dose of common sense) not to lose an acquired privilege due to a loss of rep?
- Is simplicity in this area (no rep = no privilege) offering the best service for the community or there are better ways to go?

Comment: I don't think that this page considers ways to lose reputation as either good or bad. It would need to keep track of the good reputation (positive + "non-bad" negative stuff) and bad reputation (downvotes, (deleted users/questions??)) and I don't think that this is worth the effort.

Comment: The system already keeps track of the causes of gain/loss of rep (as shown in your user activity page). It's just a matter of introducing a few rules to deal with it in a slightly different way. Surely not rocket science!

Comment: Meh, for anyone reasonably active on SO this will have solved itself within hours in most cases. It seems hardly worth the developer effort to change the system even if it were fairer in these edge cases.

Comment: It depends on the specific scenario - So in your case it wouldn't make a big difference if you could continue reviewing, but if you earn lot's of upvotes on a single post that gets deleted at one point, then you can potentially drop very much below the required reputation limit, and in that case you should first earn back the lost reputation (So I don't think a change is required)

Comment: Bounties of course are a factor, if you'd want to bounty any question right now, you'd lose your privilege again probably for quite some time if you put up a decently sized one. I'm more of the mindset that you should lose privileges when you drop down to half their rep-requirement again myself.

Comment: I'm not sure the threshold of "half" suggested by Gimby is a good one, but some sort of "oh, you dipped below" buffer should exist. It could be time based ("what was the highest your rep has been in the last X days?") or point based ("as long as you were ever above X, provided you remain above X-Y") or some combination thereof.  Hitting exactly 2000 and hitting downvote and dropping to 1999, losing the privilege ("good job doing the right thing, now lets take this away from you now...") feels backwards.

Comment: +1 for canvassing for a badge ;-)

Comment: Side note: In a perfect world, and the community agreed with your downvote, the answer would be deleted. On deletion, you will get your reputation back. The problem is we do not live in a perfect world. Possible the problem is, it takes 5 downvotes to invalidate one upvote.

Comment: Something like what @Draco18s suggests makes a lot of sense.  Once you have a privilege, do not take it off unless rep drops below, say 90% of the points required for it, or falls and stays below the required points for more than 2 weeks or a month.  But you could also avoid this problem another way - give enough rep away, through bounties, that you never get the privilege in the first place.  It's a nice fringe benefit of being generous with your rep points.... and I agree with Aidan, +1 for the canvassing.

Comment: I think it's nonsense to lose privileges due to a deduction of points when setting a bounty on a question.

Comment: I think in this particular situation, the system is working towards an equilibrium. Editing while below 2000 rep will get you points, so the first approved edit will already bring you up to the threshold again!

Comment: @MrLister [Not necessarily true](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/311489/424903)

Comment: @MrLister I dropped below 2000 rep a couple of times when reviewing - I did in fact just suggest an edit, and instantly got back my rep.

Comment: I loose my privileges to bounties. It takes me months to get the rep back. Award other people for their help and get penalized for it. Still, first world problems I guess...

Answer (score 15):

Let's consider the ways of losing reputation:

- **Getting downvoted**

If providing good posts is considered an adequately good measure of how responsible you'd be with some given privileges, it makes sense that providing bad posts implies you won't be responsible. Whether this is actually a good measure is a different story entirely.

- **Downvoting others**

[If downvoting is so important, why does it cost reputation?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/62130/if-downvoting-is-so-important-why-does-it-cost-reputation)

The idea is that downvotes are supposed to have an associated cost to be somewhat discouraged (so you only downvote where it's deserved). The cost is reputation, and sometimes privileges.

While you might not want to downvote someone while you're on some boundary where 1 reputation will make a difference in privileges, most would probably argue that you can just post some answer or even just provide a constructive edit somewhere (if you have < 2k reputation) to cancel this out.

The rest of the time it shouldn't really make a difference in terms of privileges, at least not until you look at your downvote stats and you're like "holy crap, if I hadn't downvoted all those posts, I'd have so much reputation and so many privileges right now".

- **Posting bounties**

I guess you can argue something similar to the above here.

- **Unaccepted answers and vote reversals** (manual or from voting fraud or removed users)

The argument here is that the votes / accept, along with any associated benefits received from them, should be removed. It thus makes sense to remove any privileges received too.

---

I personally agree that casting downvotes and bounties should have costs or limits, although I don't feel the cost should be reputation, but that's just my opinion.

Comment: That make sense but it would be very difficult to implement this type of calculation, and for something that is very limited and minor. I think that once you reach the minimal privilege requirements, you should be able to have it, even if your reputation suddenly dropped by, let say... -15 reputation (If for example your answer was unaccepted when you've just reached the privilege reputation. It would be easier to implement and address the valid points on your answer

Comment: @AlonEitan What kind of difficult-to-implement calculations? One way is `if (reputation >= X) givePrivilege(Y)`, the other way is that plus `if (reputation < X) removePrivilege(Y)`. It doesn't seem hard either way.

Comment: Oh, wait, I think I misread the bottom line _"I personally **agree** that casting downvotes and bounties **should have** costs or limits,"_ and for some reason I thought you meant  something different. So yes, if you too agree then my first comment is irrelevant

Comment: A good solution for the down-voting might be to simply refund the reputation if an answer is severely down-voted/deleted. A way of acknowledging a proper choice as rewarding, not costly.

Comment: @Sh4d0wsPlyr AFAIK reputation is already refunded if the answer ends up being deleted (although there might be some cutoff date i.t.o the difference between the downvoting and deletion dates). I tend to be more bothered by downvoting a "bad" answer that's significantly upvoted, since the only effect my downvote there tends to have is decreasing my own reputation (and sometimes **increasing** theirs because of "upvoted because of downvote" voters).

Comment: As a low-reputation user, losing commenting privilege because of a bounty is quite annoying

Comment: "I personally agree that casting downvotes and bounties should have costs or limits, although I don't feel the cost should be reputation" - I think good solution would be to give users certain number of free downvotes per day - this would make them more "valuable" and still discourage casual/mass downvoting. And as soon as the limit is reached, one would start paying with their own rep like it happens now.

Answer (score 1):

I don't see how this is a problem, since the SO vote mechanics are designed for heavy rep inflation.

- For each up-vote on a question you get 5 points.
- For each up-vote on an answer you get 10 points.
- Up-voting is free.

And of course there are other ways to gain rep, too. Accepted answers, editing etc.

Compare this with the -1 rep lost for down-voting and -2 for getting down-voted. If you post an answer and get one single up-vote, you can use the rep gained for as much as 10 down votes.

If anything is a problem here, it is that up-votes counts differently than down-votes. This is unfortunate since down-votes have proven to be a quite efficient quality tool over the years.

Comment: I would agree, it is a good "tool" to prevent trolling while at the same keeping the costs negligible

Comment: Exactly I agree, the number of votes and point sizes makes losing privileges very rare unless you go Bounty crazy. Upvotes should be weighted more IMHO because it takes a lot more effort to get an upvote and downvotes the person could have misread or be new and that should not be  penalized the same as a upvote. For significant downvotes you get sin binned...

Comment: I think SO's vote mechanics are fair. I think the reputation gained for receiving upvotes should be higher than the reputation lost for downvoting or getting downvoted. This probably gives members an incentive to contribute and rewards them for their efforts. Additionally, it is easier to gain privileges and keep them if reputation increases faster than it decreases. If upvotes and downvotes become equal, reputation and privileges could be lost more easily and it may be more difficult to earn them in the first place.